# Toggle table visibility w/ click

Tags: reporting-services, onclick, click, ssrs-2008, visibility

I have a ssrs simple table with a text box above it.

[image]

I want to add an image with an expand collapse option, and initially when the report is show hide the table, and when the image is clicked show and continue to toggle everytime it is clicked.

For example:

Initially:

[image]

After Click:

[image]

The image name is expand_collapse, the table name is error_table. I know I need to right an expression for the visibility properties of error_table, I have not found anything with a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by checking the toggle display box:

[image: Toggle box for visibility in SSRS]

Set the name of the text box containing your Error(8) statistics from the dropdown.

This creates a little +/- box that looks like this when collapsed:
[image]
And like this:[image] when uncollapsed.

The "When the report is initially run" option sets the state when the report is first run, so if you want it to be collapse to start, select "Hide" as I've done above.

Comment: Perfect, not sure why i didn't see that. Thanks.